# Question about AttachmentPart. What order do the attachments come?

Tags: java, soap

I have code that calls a SOAP web service that includes attachments. Here is the java code (a piece of it) where I get the attachment(s)

```
Iterator<?> i = soapResponse.getAttachments();
Object obj = null;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("file found");
    AttachmentPart att = (AttachmentPart) i.next();
    //now I want to use the DocumentID tag(from the XML response) of this
    // attachment )
```

When I call the SOAP web service in SOAP UI, here is the part of the XML response that corresponds to the attachments

```
 <ns2:result xsi:type="ns0:DocumentDetails" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns0:Content>
               <xop:Include href="cid:e01fe52d-2ddf-4ad0-a556-f5ecc0f313ce" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns0:Content>
            <ns0:FileName xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:ContentType xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:DocumentTitle>CWT_BTA_ORCLGB-20190604.zip</ns0:DocumentTitle>
            <ns0:DocumentAuthor>madeUpEmail@oracle.com</ns0:DocumentAuthor>
            <ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>FAFusionImportExport</ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>
            <ns0:DocumentAccount>prj$/projectFoundation$/import$</ns0:DocumentAccount>
            <ns0:DocumentName>CWT_BTA_ORCLGB-20190604.zip</ns0:DocumentName>
            <ns0:DocumentId>32331748</ns0:DocumentId>
         </ns2:result>
         <ns2:result xsi:type="ns0:DocumentDetails" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns0:Content>
               <xop:Include href="cid:bbbbc837-f738-4a86-8721-d06f6fb0fa16" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns0:Content>
            <ns0:FileName xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:ContentType xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:DocumentTitle>CWT_BTA_ORCLUS-20190705.zip</ns0:DocumentTitle>
            <ns0:DocumentAuthor>madeupEmail@oracle.com</ns0:DocumentAuthor>
            <ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>FAFusionImportExport</ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>
            <ns0:DocumentAccount>prj$/projectFoundation$/import$</ns0:DocumentAccount>
            <ns0:DocumentName>CWT_BTA_ORCLUS-20190705.zip</ns0:DocumentName>
            <ns0:DocumentId>32331767</ns0:DocumentId>
```

As you can see, there are two attachments: CWT_BTA_ORCLGB-20190604.zip and CWT_BTA_ORCLUS-20190705.zip ,contained in the DocumentName tag but they also have DocumentID

My question is, is the order of the attachments in my java code (the while loop that I have above) is the same as the order in the XML response? I am planning on parsing the XML response to get the DocumentIDs in an array, and then iterate through that array inside the while loop to get the corresponding "documentID" of each attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*assuming your using mulitpart MIME...*

Re:  https://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments

The above reference states that the linkage can be from either the Document-ID or the Content-Location (absolute or relative) to the other MIME attachments.  Nothing in this note or W3C recommendation (that I could find) states there is either an expected or required order of attachments.

I recommend matching Document-ID from the SOAP message to the Document-ID in the MIME part.

Comment: I understand what you mean by "matching Document-ID from SOAP message" but not by "Document-ID in the MIME part. What is the MIME part?

Comment: Re: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/toc.htmI

In your code above you iterate on MIME attachment parts.  Each AttachmentPart has a .getContentId() method, which returns a string that can be used to match against the SOAP message content (which has the reference document identities).  Does this make sense?  I assumed you are using an HTTP response (vice mail), which means that any response with documents will be in the form of an MIME instead of HTML (or text, or json, etc.)